# Azure AD Graph API not returning User GUID for Create User

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

This is the URL of the post format that i am sending the request in.

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6`

I am also attaching the Authentication header value Bearer with access token.
            `request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);`

I am requesting with these elements in the body

`Content-type: application/json`

```js
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

Source : [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser)

This is the response I am getting

```js
{StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 19:11:40 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Location: https://graph.windows.net/metadata/directoryObjects/metadata/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: servername
  request-id: req id
  client-request-id: client request id
  x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.6
  ocp-aad-session-key: some random keys
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Duration: 4425304
  Content-Length: 1271
  Content-Type: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

But i am unable to find any Userdata / GUID as mentioned in the Source link above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you posted only contains the headers. There is also a JSON body (the headers include `Content-Length: 1271`).

As you can see in [the link you posted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser), the response body contains the new user information, including the user's `objectId`, so you should parse the body.

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating [Azure Active Directory Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) with [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/). These are two distinct APIs. While Microsoft Graph API is replacing AAD Graph, they have different methods and payload so the code is not interchangeable between the two. They also use different tokens.

When you're [creating a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users), you'll want to `POST` that JSON payload to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` not `https://graph.windows.net/...`.

You'll also want to make sure you request the [User.ReadWrite.All](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) scope and that you're either using a Global Administrator account or have had a Global Admin go through the [Admin Consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#azure-ad-endpoint-considerations) flow. This will give your the required permissions to create a user in the directory.

Comment: will i be able to pass the `vendorid` if i try using mirosoft graph api ? or maybe i just linked the wrong URL. 
should have been this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser

Comment: I'm not sure what `vendorid` is to be honest. I couldn't find it referenced in the documentation you linked to either.

Comment: sorry my bad, `vendorid` aka `myorganization` in 

`POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version`

Comment: You don't provide `/myorganization/` in calls to Microsoft Graph. The API will automatically handle routing your call to the Azure AD you've authenticated too.